# Access data in a "column" of an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I access the data in y "column" in data1 array and push the data to a new array data2?

```
var data1 = [
  {x:1, y:3, s:0.15},
  {x:2, y:2.7, s:0.1},
  {x:0.7, y:3, s:0.15},
  {x:2.3, y:2.9, s:0.12}
];

var data2 = [3, 2.7, 3, 2.9]
```

This is what I tried:

```
var data2 = [];
for (var j = 0; j < data1.length; j++) {
  if ( ) {
    data2.push( );
  };
};
```

I am not a javascript user. Appreciate if anyone help to finish it!

Comment: To mkae your code work, you should just have to remove the `if` statement and use `data2.push(data1[j].y)`. You might want to read http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this

```js
var data1 = [
  {x: 1, y: 3, s: 0.15},
  {x: 2, y: 2.7, s: 0.1},
  {x: 0.7, y: 3, s: 0.15},
  {x: 2.3, y: 2.9, s: 0.12}          
];

var data2 = data1.map(function (e) {
  return e.y;
})

console.log(data2);
```

or modify your version like this

```js
var data1 = [
  {x: 1, y: 3, s: 0.15},
  {x: 2, y: 2.7, s: 0.1},
  {x: 0.7, y: 3, s: 0.15},
  {x: 2.3, y: 2.9, s: 0.12}          
];

var data2 = [];
for (var j = 0; j < data1.length; j++) {
  data2.push(data1[j].y);
};

console.log(data2);
```